# non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, function, binary, numeric

I have a data frame T that is a mixture of numeric and string:

```
 T1<-c(1,2, 3,4,6)
 T2<-c(4,5, 5,7,8)
 T3<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
 T4<-c(4,5, 5,7,8)
 T5<-c(4,5, 5,7,8)
 T<-data.frame(T1,T2,T3,T4,T5)
```

When I apply function to the numeric value of each row using follwong code:

```
  P=apply(T,1,FUN=function(x) ifelse(x[1]>=x[4]+2*x[5],1,0))
```

It always give error message "Error in 2 * x[5] : non-numeric argument to binary operator". But if I replace T3 with all numeric values, it works perfectly.

I am puzzled by this and wondering anyone has any insight?

thanks!

Comment: You are using `apply` to a `data.frame`. `apply` is meant for `array` objects and so it converts `T` to a `matrix`. Since your `data.frame` contains `character` column, it will be coerced to a `character` matrix and so arithmetic operations are not allowed.

Comment: @D Jay You could have just used `(T[,1]>=T[,4]+2*T[,5])+0`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, that made the point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get coercion of each row to character because T3 is included in what is passed from your dataframe to the function by `apply`. You could fix this with:

```
P=apply(T[-3],1,FUN=function(x) ifelse(x[1]>=x[3]+2*x[4],1,0))
```

The error is not from the comparison but rather from the attempt to multiply a character value by a numeric. It also might have succeeded with:

```
P=apply(T,1,FUN=function(x) ifelse(as.numeric(x[1])>= as.numeric(x[4])+ 
                                                  2*as.numeric(x[5])
                                   ,1,0))
```

But this is "just wrong". The use of `apply` is appropriate for matrices where all  modes of the columns are the same, but it is generally slower than vectorized functions like `ifelse` which offer row-wise processing without resorting to `apply`. Should be:

```
P=with(T,  ifelse(T1 >= T4 +  2*T5, 1,0) )
```

Or just use Boolean arithmetic and convert back to numeric 0/1:

```
P=  with(T, as.numeric( T1 >= T4 +  2*T5 ) ) # @akrun gets the check
```

Comment: Ya know, @akrun has a great point. Shouldn't even use apply for this.

Comment: Gotcha. I shifted the positions. But using `ifelse` inside an apply call is just wrong.